# KendoGrid custom filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

Added a custom filter called 'between' to my number field in KendoGrid with input fields to filter the numbers between the given range.On filtering I'm getting an exception

[Between Filter Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nqIN.png)

```
Uncaught TypeError: $[(u || "eq").toLowerCase(...)] is not a function
```

How should i resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you please add the code for your grid to your original post? That will help us see how you are setting up the filter and give you a better answer.

Comment: More code would help a bit.